# Creating MOCK UP Data for Neo4j Unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, neo4j, junit5

I want to do unit testing for my application in neo4j with java code .We are writing junit test cases for it. But we want when we run the junit test cases it should not communicate it to the main database rather then some other mockup data.

**We are using neo4j server and no embedded database is used.**

> How could this be achieved?
>
> How can we create mockup data for testing neo4j related code?
>
> How to create a mocked database for unit testing so that main database
>   not be touched.
>
> Is there any tool to mock the main database or we have to do it
>   manually through the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've got a great article on [testing your Neo4j-based Java application](https://medium.com/neo4j/testing-your-neo4j-based-java-application-34bef487cc3c) that should give you a few options for testing.

Comment: its for embedded database . I m searching for neo4j server that is on remote location. Using bolt driver for it.

Comment: If you scroll down to the section that starts with "General setup of Testcontainers with JUnit 5", that should be applicable to your case, providing a test container that you can start up (and add data to before tests) and test your code upon.

Answer (score 0):

An option is Neo4j for Test Containers.

If you use Maven (or a compatible tool), another option is [this Maven plug-in](https://github.com/Rothamsted/neo4j-server-maven-plugin), which I'm still maintaining.

Test containers are maybe simpler and with a community of users, the plug-in way allows for a self-contained build: once you have Java and Maven, nothing else is needed, while Test containers require the Docker Daemon.